How can I create a Markdown to PDF table with the striped style? (Quarto)
I want to use the striped style (as explained here) in a pdf table, but it doesn't work.
The table is a normal Markdown table in a Quarto document, so it's not the result of any computations.
I tried the Bootstrap classes as explained in the link above. That doesn't work for pdf.
| Col1 | Col2  |
|------|-------|
| ABC  | DEF   |
| GHI  | JKL   |

: caption {.striped}


Please add a [mre] to your question

(and if you have some time, I would suggest reading one of the books by Edward Tufte to understand why such striped tables are a bad idea)

ok, unfortunately I have no time at this moment to read this book(s). I want create a table with borders, stripes or whatever. Important is the boundary of the rows (and columns). The table contains only text.

You could use \rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray!50} from the colortbl package to add colours to the rows:
---
format: pdf
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{colortbl}\rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray!50}
---

| Col1 | Col2  |
|------|-------|
| ABC  | DEF   |
| GHI  | JKL   |
| ABC  | DEF   |
| GHI  | JKL   |

: caption {.striped}


